# How is this rope implementation correct?

Tags: python, string, debugging, data-structures, ropes

I was trying to solve a programming problem that involved a lot of insertions into a list. The specifics of the problem are not relevant to the question, however.

To solve it, I ended up writing some kind of a rope data structure, trying to piece an implementation together from the scarce resources I was able to find on the internet.

I ended up writing this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import typing as t

from hypothesis import given, strategies as st

T = t.TypeVar("T")


@dataclass
class Branch(t.Generic[T]):
    weight: int
    left: t.Union[t.List[T], "Branch[T]"]
    right: t.Union[t.List[T], "Branch[T]"]


Rope = t.Union[t.List[T], Branch[T]]


def insert(rope: Rope, index: int, item: T) -> Rope:
    if isinstance(rope, list):  # leaf
        if index == len(rope):  # at the end, just append
            rope.append(item)
            return rope

        # split
        left, right = rope[:index], [item, *rope[index:]]
        return Branch(len(left), left, right)
    else:  # branch
        if rope.right and rope.weight <= index:
            rope.right = insert(rope.right, index - rope.weight, item)
        else:
            rope.weight += 1
            rope.left = insert(rope.left, index, item)

        return rope


def straighten(rope: Rope) -> t.Iterator[T]:
    if isinstance(rope, list):
        yield from rope
    else:
        yield from straighten(rope.left)
        yield from straighten(rope.right)


@st.composite
def instructions(draw, elements=st.integers(0, 255)):
    items = draw(st.lists(elements, min_size=1))
    result = []
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        insertion_point = draw(st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=i))
        result.append((insertion_point, item))
    return result


@given(instructions())
def test_correctness(seq: t.List[t.Tuple[int, int]]) -> None:
    manual: t.List[int] = []
    for (i, item) in seq:
        manual.insert(i, item)

    rope: Rope = []
    for (i, item) in seq:
        rope = insert(rope, i, item)

    assert manual == list(
        straighten(rope)
    ), f"{manual!r} != {rope!r} => {list(straighten(rope))!r}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_correctness()
    print("All good")
```

As you can see, the code passes the hypothesis and, therefore, it solves the problem.

I am unable to understand however *why* this code I wrote is correct, as trying to rewrite it utilizing just Branches and leaves (that is to say, without using lists) yields an incorrect implementation:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import typing as t

from hypothesis import given, strategies as st

T = t.TypeVar("T")


@dataclass
class Branch(t.Generic[T]):
    weight: int
    left: t.Union[T, "Branch[T]"]
    right: t.Union[T, "Branch[T]"]


Rope = t.Union[T, Branch[T]]


def insert(rope: Rope, index: int, item: T) -> Rope:
    if isinstance(rope, Branch):  # leaf
        if rope.right and rope.weight <= index:
            rope.right = insert(rope.right, index - rope.weight, item)
        else:
            rope.weight += 1
            rope.left = insert(rope.left, index, item)

        return rope

    if index == 0:
        left, right = item, rope
    else:
        left, right = rope, item

    return Branch(1, left, right)


def straighten(rope: Rope) -> t.Iterator[T]:
    if isinstance(rope, Branch):
        yield from straighten(rope.left)
        yield from straighten(rope.right)
    else:
        yield rope


@st.composite
def instructions(draw, elements=st.integers(0, 255)):
    items = draw(st.lists(elements, min_size=1))
    result = []
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        insertion_point = draw(st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=i))
        result.append((insertion_point, item))
    return result


@given(instructions())
def test_correctness(seq: t.List[t.Tuple[int, int]]) -> None:
    it = iter(seq)
    _, head = next(it)

    rope: Rope = head
    manual = [head]
    for (i, item) in it:
        manual.insert(i, item)
        rope = insert(rope, i, item)

        straight_rope: t.List[int] = list(straighten(rope))
        assert manual == straight_rope, f"{manual!r} != {straight_rope!r} ({rope!r})"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_correctness()
    print("All good")
```

So I'd appreciate if anybody with more insight into this data structure would tell me the difference between the two implementations and why one works while the other doesn't. Thank you ina dvance.

Comment: `if rope.right` doesn't mean what you wanted it to mean.

Comment: I'll try removing that check and see what happens, I hadn't thought about that while translating. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because in `if rope.right and rope.weight <= index:`, the condition evaluates to `False` when `rope.right == 0`. In your second code this happens when the right node is a leaf with value 0, and will cause the value to be inserted into the wrong subtree.

There is no reason for checking `rope.right` at all, so this check should simply be `if rope.weight <= index:`.

There is another potential issue in both of your rope implementations: You are mutating nodes, while rope implementations normally treat nodes as immutable and create new nodes to make any changes. This doesn't affect your tests because you only have one rope instance at a time. An example where it would cause issues:

```
r = create_some_rope()
r2 = r
r = insert(r, idx, val)
# now r2 may or may not have changed, depending on its structure.
```

It will also cause issues if you ever add rope concatenation. In that case, if you concatenate a rope to itself (or to a subtree of itself), then any further operations may inadvertently affect multiple parts of the rope.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Do you mean that even in the first implementation the check is redundant?

Comment: @PurpleMyst It doesn't seem to accomplish anything useful in the first implementation either. It checks for an empty list, but I don't see a reason to do that.